# Google Maps detecting marker click inside event.addlistener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Currently i have a `bounds_changed` listener that is clearing the marker overlays and then recreating the markers inside the map bounds.

However whenever a marker is clicked and the map moves the infowindow does not display. Since it's wiped out. How do I ad an if statement to the following that will detect if a click on the marker was done and if so do nothing else `clearOverlays` and `createMarkers`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() { 
        //alert(map.getBounds()); 
        clearOverlays();
        createMarkers(map, mgr);          
    });
```

for example

```
if(marker.click) {
} else {
    clearOverlays();
    createMarkers(map, mgr);      
}
```

Final working code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() { 
        if(checkevent == false)
        {
            //alert(checkevent);
            clearOverlays();
            createMarkers(map, mgr);          
        }
    });
```

and in the listener for the marker click

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker5, 'click', function() { checkevent = true;  infowindow5.open(map,marker5); setTimeout('checkevent = false', 3000); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a listener for marker click events, set a state variable scoped externally to the event listener. In your bounds_changed listener, check the state variable. Always reset the state variable at the end of the bound_changed listener.

Comment: I set a checkevent variable to false.
Then add to the listener event checkevent = true and at the end checkevent = false.


I had to do a set timeout of about 3 seconds to get to work smoothly fyi. But otherwise works like a charm!

Thanks